# Lost the current data when changing the Serial Port - Baud Rate

Tags: c#, serial-port

I attempt to get data from the device via Serial Port with ReadExisting() receive method.

At the first point, I send request to the device with baud rate 300. Then, device answers back with the same baud rate. I confirm this answer before changing baud rate to 9600 (set serialport.baudrate = 9600 after sending the confirm command).

My trouble is losing the data in the buffer after changing baud rate (the ReadExisting() method can not read this?). But the next command at baud rate 9600 still receives the answer from device.
How can we solve that? Many thanks.

E.g:

PC: Request handshake (300bps)

Device: Answer (300bps)

PC: Confirm the device's answer (300bps)

Device: The data's lost (I try to receive here)

---------- Changing baud rate to 9600 --------------

Device: The data's lost (I try to receive here too)

PC: Send the next command (9600bps)

Device: Answer (9600bps)

PC: Send the next command (9600bps)

Device: Answer (9600bps)

Comment: You have to check the status bits of the UART and clear any errors and ignore data associated with bad data.  If the device automatically send continuous data the data in the receive buffer is no good after you changed rates and has to be cleared.

Comment: As for the theory, the data will receive at baud rate 9600. But I can not receive at all. Might my receive's event too slow to get this data? For your former mention, how can I check the status bits and avoid this from remove?

Comment: If you are using events (and not timers) you will be able to receive all the data.  For errors see msdn : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialerror?view=netframework-4.8